# How to overwrite Ubuntu with Windows 7?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7, ntfs, ext4

So I have a Windows DVD and it works. But when it gets to the part when it says "Upgrade" or "Custom" I click on custom and at the bottom it says cannot install over it because Windows 7 can only be installed on an NTFS drive? I know that Ubuntu formatted my partitions into one big on that's an ext4. What can I do?

I know that I can maybe create a 30-50 GB partition that's an ntfs then when I go into windows I can format the Ubuntu one and combine them but I don't know how to make a partition much less make a big partition in the "GParted" program? So any ideas would be very helpful. I know how to do anything with a hard drive using the default program that comes with Windows 7 but I feel like a mouse in a maze when I open GParted.

Comment: Erase the partition, format it with the Windows DVD, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot from the Windows install media and at the Drive Setup screen click Drive options (advanced). On that resulting screen, select each partition individually and click Delete. Once done you will see one entry for "Unallocated Space". Select that, and click next. Windows will create it's ~100MB System partition and format the rest as your C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

A few tutorials (:.
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-sq3PBzplYg
I mean honestly, they aren't step for step, but they have the same concept.
Goodluck!